# meaning of "." after first element in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

what is difference between `numpy.array([[1., 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])` and `numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`. I came across one code using two different type of declaration but could not find its meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1.` is a floating point number, `1` is an integer. In the case of `numpy`, this seems to affect the entire array, i.e. if one number is a floating point number, all the numbers are converted accordingly.

```
In [3]: numpy.array([[1., 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.]])

In [4]: numpy.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

In the first case, all the numbers in the array get the type `numpy.float64`, while in the latter case they get `numpy.int64`.

Comment: NumPy arrays are designed and optimized around the idea that every element has the same number of bytes in memory. NumPy detects that one element is a float and upcasts the rest of the values accordingly when it allocates memory.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the array. `1.` means `1.0`. `1.` is a float, `1` is an int.